# Running python unit test in Google Cloud Build

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-build

I would like Google Cloud Build to run the unit test I have in my python project after pushing the changes. 
I am able to configure the step that runs the test, but I am not sure how to input the directory the holds the test and if I just put `.` then it run 0 test

my project structure is:
- project_name
  - package_name
    - test
      - sample_test.py

This is my `cloudbuild.yaml` configuration:

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ["run","gcr.io/google-appengine/python","python3","-m","unittest","discover","--verbose","-s","./package_name/test/","-p","*_test.py"]
      id:   unittest
```

The above fails with this message:

```
raise ImportError('Start directory is not importable: %r' % start_dir)
ImportError: Start directory is not importable: './package_name/test/'
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
Show debug panel
```

And if I replace the folder with just `.` then it runs but does not discover any tests.
For copying the code to gs buckets, we use gsutil and then ./package_name copies the package to the bucket
Locally this of course works

How can I understand what is the correct folder structure for my tests to run?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

1. Why do you use `appengine` container? Why not just use an official Python container - `name: python:3.7`?
   Steps run as Docker containers, and I see no reason to run Docker in docker when you want to run docker container.
   Try this:

```
steps:
  - name: python:3.7
    args: ["python","-m","unittest","discover","--verbose","-s","./package_name/test/","-p","*_test.py"]
    id: unittest
```

2. Also, do you have `__init__.py` file in the directory `./package_name/test`? The message `directory is not importable` usually means that this directory is not a Python package because of missing `__init__.py` file.